# How to change this specific TOC margin in memoir

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir

How to edit this specific margin in the book I have been editing...
The red arrows in the pictures below....because the TOC of this book is kind of long so it goes to the next page, and I believe that the space in the first TOC page could be better used.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/udRgvsa.jpg]

I have seen some topic about SIMILAR questions, although they talk about external margins, side margins or space between items... which is not the case.

Is there a way to reduce the red arrow margin?

If necessary, I can add a MWE as well, but I am not using anything different than `\tableofcontents*` in this page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\tableofcontents` is set like any other chapter under [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) and uses the chapter-related settings for spacing. Specifically, the `\aftertoctitle` macro governs what happens `after` the `toc` `title`. The default is to match `\afterchaptertitle`, so we can update this to suit our needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlength{\aftertocskip}
\setlength{\aftertocskip}{2\baselineskip}% Space after ToC title
\renewcommand{\aftertoctitle}{\par\nobreak\vskip\aftertocskip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to reduce this distance between title and text in ONE specific chapter?

Comment: @Adriano: You mean the space below `Heading on level 0 (chapter)` and above `Lorem ipsum` on page 3 of my minimal example?

Comment: Yes, precisely that space.

Comment: @Adriano: You can use `{\setlength{\afterchapskip}{10pt}\chapter{A chapter}}\noindent` where you adjust `10pt` to suit your needs. Note that I've placed the `\setlength` and `\chapter` inside a group, so it only affects that chapter's adjustment.